# Java print a template

Tags: java, html, printing

The problem is pretty simple but I cant find a straight-forward solution online.

I have a document template, which I want to be able to populate with information (different information, more than once) and then print. My initial thought was to create a html template, and then send a parsed version to the print.

I suppose there is more than one question here:

- What is the best approach to solve this problem?
- If the HTML parsing is the best solution can someone point me in the correct direction as I dont know where to start.

Thanks.

-- EDIT: a better example to clear up any confusion.

On a java GUI program, the user is able to pull up a customers information. I wish them to be able to print an invoice at the click of a button. My current problem is deciding how to populate the invoice with the customers information and send it to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a web [HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). Let the user populate the input fields and pass them in the POST body when a form submit button is pressed. Then you analyze the input and create the final document version (on the server) and only then return the document to the client with an appropriate MIME type in the response header (that's how you enable the printing).

For example (simple form with submit button)

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
     Username: <input type="text" name="user">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

EDIT:

For building document template take a look on [playframework](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaHome).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but I think you misunderstood. I have client information stored in a database and a java GUI app. I want to, for example, on the click of a button by the user, populate a document with, for example customers name and id, various products related to the customer, and then print the document.

Comment: You did not mention the above in your question (care to update?). In this case you will need java backing bean to represent the document fields. Once you populated the bean from DB printing is straight-forward.

Comment: My main problem resides with printing a parsed version of a html file rather than the tags as plaintext. As far as populating a HTML template goes I am able to do that. I was also wondering if there were for example any libraries I could alternatively use. Sorry if my question was ambiguous.

Comment: I see. You can take look at playframework. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaHome